# How to find out the number of entries or size of table in the Accumulo?

Tags: accumulo

I have inserted data into accumulo. But how would i know the exact count of the table ?
Is there any method or API to read the accumulo table size of number of entries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to do it programatically?  If not, there are various ways that you can do this.  The easiest is to go to the Accumulo monitor page on port `50095`.  If you don't have a ton of data, from the command line you can simply do

```
accumulo shell -u username -p password -e "scan -t foo -np" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, Accumulo doesn't know the exact size of a table during active ingest -- it will be an approximate. I don't think any public API methods exist to get this information, although there are some internal methods you could call. Something like the following should work:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(instance, credentials, clientConfiguration);
MasterClientService.Iface client = null;
MasterMonitorInfo mmi = null;
while (null == mmi) {
  try {
    client = MasterClient.getConnection(context);
    if (client != null) {
      mmi = client.getMasterStats(Tracer.traceInfo(), context.rpcCreds())
    }
  } finally {
    if (null != client) {
      MasterClient.close(client);
    }
  }
}
for (Entry<String,TableInfo> table : mmi.getTableMap().entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(table.getKey() + "=>" + (table.getValue().recs + table.getValue().recsInMemory));
}
```

This is similar to how the Accumulo monitor obtains these values. Because these are internal APIs, they're a little rough to use and may change across releases. If you'd like to see these APIs exposed through the normal Instance or Connector methods, please open an issue on the [project's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue.jspa) instance!